# Erratic zoom on force directed graph with D3.js v4

Tags: d3.js, graph, zooming

I have this force directed graph in D3.js (v4):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    svg text {
         pointer-events: none;     
    }   
</style>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var  r = 7, w=window.innerWidth, h=window.innerHeight, nodes = [], colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);
    var force = d3.forceSimulation()
            .velocityDecay(0.9)
            .alphaDecay(0)
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())   
            .force("repel", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-140).distanceMax(100).distanceMin(10))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(w /2, h/2))
            .force("x", d3.forceX(w / 2))
            .force("y", d3.forceY(h / 2));

    var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.3, 8])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h)
            .call(zoom);  

 d3.json("tiles1.json", function (data) {
        var root = d3.hierarchy(data); 
        var nodes = root.descendants(); 
        var links = root.links(); 
        force.nodes(nodes); 
        force.force("link", d3.forceLink(links).strength(1).distance(50));
          var link = svg.selectAll("line")
              .data(links)
              .enter().insert("line")
              .style("stroke", "#999")
              .style("stroke-width", "1px");
          var nodeElements = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
              .data(nodes)
              .enter().append("circle")
              .attr("r", r)
              .style("fill", function(d) {
                  return colors(d.parent && d.parent.data.name); 
              })
              .style("stroke", "#0b5698")
                .call(d3.drag()
                      .on("start", dragStarted)
                      .on("drag", dragged)
                      .on("end", dragEnded));

        var labels = svg.selectAll(".mytext")
         .data(nodes)
         .enter()
         .append("text")
          .attr("dx", 12)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.data.name })
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .style("fill", "#555")
                        .style("font-family", "Arial")
                        .style("font-size", 7);

      force.on("tick", function(e) {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
            nodeElements.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
            labels.attr("x", function(d){ return d.x -10; })
                 .attr("y", function (d) {return d.y + 10; });
          });
 });

    function dragStarted(d) {
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
    }
    function dragged(d) {
        d.fx = d3.event.x;
        d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }
    function dragEnded(d) {
        d.fx = null;
        d.fy = null;
    }
    function zoomed() {
        svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The tiles1.json is bellow; I use a graph with only two nodes for the sake of simplicity here.

```
{    "name": "test", "children": [{
            "name": "test"
        }]
}
```

Everything is working fine, except the zoom action: instead of centering the zoom in the point of the click, the entire graph is practically translating to the upper-left corner, [0,0] origin, even if my center origin of the graph is the center of the screen (`d3.forceCenter(w/2, h/2)`).

I am not a big expert in D3, but I am aware that I did something wrong in the code, or something is missing and I don't understand what and why.

I need your help, thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things:

1. The thing that you call `.call(zoom)` on is the event handler, the element looking for the events that are going to zoom.  This should not be the SVG directly.  The usual form is to put an invisible rect on top of the SVG to catch these events.
2. You can not apply the an SVG zoom to the `svg` element in the way you are doing.  This is a little counter intuitive but the `svg` tag is an HTML element, things inside of it are `svg` elements.  So, what do you do?  Wrap your drawing in a `g` that you apply the zoom on.

Putting these two ideas together and you end up with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
    svg text {
         pointer-events: none;     
    }   
</style>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var  r = 7, w=window.innerWidth, h=window.innerHeight, nodes = [], colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20c);
    var force = d3.forceSimulation()
            .velocityDecay(0.9)
            .alphaDecay(0)
            .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())   
            .force("repel", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-140).distanceMax(100).distanceMin(10))
            .force("center", d3.forceCenter(w /2, h/2))
            .force("x", d3.forceX(w / 2))
            .force("y", d3.forceY(h / 2));

    var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.3, 8])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);
        
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)

    var g = svg.append("g");

    svg.append("rect")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("pointer-events", "all")
      .call(zoom);   

 d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/eb8b41b1-0c23-11e7-a0ba-092e370a78bd", function (data) {
        var root = d3.hierarchy(data); 
        var nodes = root.descendants(); 
        var links = root.links(); 
        force.nodes(nodes); 
        force.force("link", d3.forceLink(links).strength(1).distance(50));
          var link = g.selectAll("line")
              .data(links)
              .enter().insert("line")
              .style("stroke", "#999")
              .style("stroke-width", "1px");
          var nodeElements = g.selectAll("circle.node")
              .data(nodes)
              .enter().append("circle")
              .attr("r", r)
              .style("fill", function(d) {
                  return colors(d.parent && d.parent.data.name); 
              })
              .style("stroke", "#0b5698")
                .call(d3.drag()
                      .on("start", dragStarted)
                      .on("drag", dragged)
                      .on("end", dragEnded));

        var labels = g.selectAll(".mytext")
         .data(nodes)
         .enter()
         .append("text")
          .attr("dx", 12)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.data.name })
                    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                        .style("fill", "#555")
                        .style("font-family", "Arial")
                        .style("font-size", 7);

      force.on("tick", function(e) {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
            nodeElements.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
            labels.attr("x", function(d){ return d.x -10; })
                 .attr("y", function (d) {return d.y + 10; });
          });
 });

    function dragStarted(d) {
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
    }
    function dragged(d) {
        d.fx = d3.event.x;
        d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }
    function dragEnded(d) {
        d.fx = null;
        d.fy = null;
    }
    function zoomed() {
        g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mark, I understood your resolution, it works. However there is one (big) problem with it: the mouse drag function on nodes has failed: the force simulation that control both nodes and links positions
by the tick function does not work anymore. When I try to drag a node with mouse, the entire graph is panning.